# Container instances keep getting created and registered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a service in ECS. I am currently trying to turn everything off so I am not charged any more money.  I have 0 pending and 0 running tasks.  There was one registered container instance so I de-registered it. I also terminated the instance in EC2. However, a few minutes after deregistering and terminating the instance, I see that a new container instance is registered and a new running EC2 instance shows up in my dashboard. Why does the instance keep re-appearing and how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have an [Auto Scaling group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingGroup.html) that is launching new instances.  The ECS documentation has a section on [cleaning up](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CleaningUp.html).